# JFormDesigner Full Screen Design

Tags: java, jform-designer

I have been working with JFormDesigner Since last 4 hours and its a quite a difficult to make it work for all size screen. What do I need is I need to make a design JFrame window size to be full screen so that my design wont get distracted when I run it in different sized computer.Please some one help me in this regard.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get size of screen and the resize the frame.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
```

hope it helps:)